# JavaScript + JSF

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

I'm developing an application that uses the google maps api in javascript and do not know how to return an array that is in my bean to my array into the javascript. Any suggestion is helpful

Answer (score 0):

What JSF framework are you using? Have you seen primefaces?
Check out gMap
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/gmapHome.jsf

Answer (score 0):

You can simply generate the JavaScript in your bean and output it from a variable example :

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean
{
    public String getMyJavaScriptArray()
    {
        // Your business logic to generate the array
        return "var mycars = new Array(); mycars[0] = \"Saab\"; mycars[1] = \"Volvo\"; mycars[2] = \"BMW\";";
    }
}

<script>
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.myJavaScriptArray}" escape="false" />
</script>
```

Or you can use this JSF GMap component :

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps4jsf/

Answer (score 0):

In your `managed bean` return the values as a comma seperated `String`.

```
public String getNames() {
  return "Thomson,John,William";
}
```

In your `javascript`, access it using `EL` and convert it again to an array as below.

```
var str = "#{myBean.text}";
var jsArray = str.split(","); //This is what you need
```